# foreach data to array laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I get the problem when I try looping the data to store in variable for making the pie chart on Laravel

**this is my code in controller**

```
// $countUser = DB::select(DB::raw("
//             SELECT r.name AS name, count(u.id) AS countUser
//             FROM users u, role_user ru, roles r
//             WHERE u.id = ru.user_id
//             AND ru.role_id = r.id
//             GROUP BY name "));
$countUser = DB::table(DB::raw('users'))
             ->select(DB::raw('roles.name AS name, count(users.id) AS countUser'))
             ->join('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
             ->join('roles', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
             ->groupByRaw('role_user.role_id, name')->get();

$data = " ";
foreach($countUser as $user){
    $data = "['".$user->name."', ".$user->countUser."],";
}

dd($data);
```

**I expect the result like this**

[image]

**but, I get the result only one**

[image]

When I try this `dd($countUser);`. This is the result

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: _"but, I get the result only one"_ - of course you do, because you are _overwriting_ `$data` in each loop iteration, instead of _appending_ to it.

Comment: You should not do this by concatenating string values together in the first place; instead, fill the appropriate array data structure, and then use `json_encode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you keep overwriting `$data`, instead lets use Laravel Collection methods to help you.

Map all your entries to the format `[$name, $count]`. Then use the Collection method `implode()`, to join the strings with a comma.

```
$concatenatedUsers = $countUser->map(function ($user) {
    return '[' . $user->name . ', ' . $user->countUser ']';
})->implode(', ');

dd($concatenatedUsers);
```